# 'CustomMetadataTypeAccesses' not valid in version 42

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, package.xml, jenkins

I'm trying to enable custom metada types to my permission sets in my metadata.xml file and deploy it to an org and I get this errir.

I've tried updating API versions in my package.xml but still no luck. Any suggestions

Comment: can you add content of your package.xml in to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also update the apiVersion in the metadata files.

To do that, you can run the following script at the root of your metatada folder (you need salesforce DX and sfdx-essentials plugin : https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx-essentials#sfdx-essentialsprojectchange-dependency-version )

```
sfdx essentials:project:change-dependency-version -a 47.0
```